# Chef - Ruby - How to extract values from a nested array/list

Tags: arrays, ruby, chef-infra

I'm using this json content (I'm open to suggestions on better formatting here):

```
{"forwardingZones": [{"name": "corp.mycompany.com","dnsServers": ["192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2"]}]}
```

Note: we may add more items to this list as we scale out, both more IPs and more names, hence the "join(',')" in the end of the code below.

And I'm trying to loop through it to get this result:

```
corp.mycompany.com=192.168.0.1;192.168.0.2
```

Using this code:

```
forward_zones = node['DNS']['forward_zones'].each do |forwarded_zone|
forwarded_zone_name = forwarded_zone['name']
forwarded_zone_dns_servers = forwarded_zone['dns_servers'].join(';')
"#{forwarded_zone_name}=#{forwarded_zone_dns_servers}"
end.join(',')
```

This is the result that I get:

```
{"dnsServers"=>["192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2"], "name"=>"corp.mycompany.com"}
```

What am i doing wrong...?

Comment: @iGian - I require the former- corp.mycompany.com=192.168.0.1;192.168.0.2 but what I'm getting is a hash.... I am trying to get rid of the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x.each` returns `x`. You want `x.map`.

Comment: How would you map them though? 
Literally like:

forward_zones = node['DNS']['forward_zones'].map do |forwarded_zone|
forwarded_zone_name = forwarded_zone['name']
forwarded_zone_dns_servers = forwarded_zone['dns_servers'].join(';')
"#{forwarded_zone_name}=#{forwarded_zone_dns_servers}"
end.join(',')

Comment: It worked!! I can't believe I overlooked something so simple.. Thanks again @David Chandler!